# Is it possible to create an SVG rect element with top left and top right rounded corners for use in D3?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am making a bar chart in D3 v4 and want each bar to have top left and top right rounded corners. The bar chart's y-axis also has negative values, so for data <0, the rect elements will have bottom left and bottom right rounded corners. Assigning rx and ry attributes rounds all four corners instead of just the aforementioned corners. Is there no equivalent to CSS's border-top-right-radius?

Comment: There's a path, you can draw anything you like with that including. rect with two rounded corners.

Comment: Thanks. So for every data element/bar in the graph I have to draw a path? This seems overly complicated for something that to me should be trivial.

Comment: you can easily make your own function for that, see [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3468167)